# LinDB: A dictionary type database

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

As an exercise, I've decided to write a lightweight, dictionary type database. Below are some of the features I've implemented:

- Overwrite Inserting: I allow the user to determine if they want to overwrite existing data, should they insert a pair that already has a value associated with the key of that pair.
- Encryption: The user can pass a 32 character long password that encrypts the database when they're done using it.
- Query Specification: The user can request a value by passing a key, request all keys associated with a particular value, or pass a pair and get the index of where that pair is in the database.

Questions:

- Security: Is how I'm implementing security "good"? I've user `Fernet` in the past, and the absolute requirement of a 32 character long password ensures it will take a considerable amount of time to break the encryption. I'm also fairly concerned about the time between each encrypt and decrypt. Should I only decrypt when the user wants to insert or query the database?
- Password Verification: I let `Fernet` decide if the password is correct, instead of implementing something myself. Is this a good way of going about this?
- Conventions: The ones I'm particular about are the double underscore ones, such as `__encrypt_db`. I'm familiar with the purpose of hiding functions that are meant to be internal. Am I using this convention correctly?
- Any other improvements that you think I can make.

**`lindb.py`**

```
"""
LinDB

@author Ben Antonellis.
@date 07-17-2020.
"""

import os
import json

import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.fernet import InvalidToken

from typing import Any, Union, List, Dict

class LinDB():

    def __init__(self, name, pw=None):
        self.name = name
        self.__pw = pw
        self.db = {}
        self.file_name = f"{self.name}.json"
        self.connected = False
        self.new_db = False

        self.encrypt = self.__pw != None
        if self.encrypt:
            if len(self.__pw) > 32:
                raise PasswordLengthError("Password must be at least 32 characters long!")
            self.__pw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(self.__pw.encode())
            self.fernet = Fernet(self.__pw)

        self.__create_db_file()

    def insert(self, pair: Dict, overwrite:bool=False) -> None:
        """
        Allows the user to insert a dictionary into the database.
        """
        if not self.connected:
            quit("Please call .connect() to connect to database!")
        
        for key in pair:
            value = pair[key]
        
        if overwrite:
            for pair_key, db_key in zip(pair, self.db):
                if pair_key == db_key:
                    self.db[db_key] = value
                    break

        self.db.update(pair)

    def query(self, key:Any=None, value:Any=None) -> Union[None, List[Any], bool]:
        """
        Querys the database for either the key or value.

        If both key and value:
            Return position in database the first pair was found.
        
        If just key:
            Return value associated with key.

        If just value:
            Return all keys with associated value.
        """
        if not self.connected:
            quit("Please call .connect() to connect to database!")
        try:
            if key and value:
                index = 0
                for k, v in self.db.items():
                    if k == key and v == value:
                        return index
                    index += 1
            if key and not value:
                return self.db[key]
            if value and not key:
                return [k for k, v in self.db.items() if v == value]
        except KeyError:
            return

    def save(self) -> None:
        """
        Saves the current database to the file.
        """
        if not self.connected:
            quit("Please call .connect() to connect to database!")
        with open(self.file_name, "w") as db_file:
            json.dump(self.db, db_file, ensure_ascii=False)

    def connect(self) -> None:
        """
        Indicates to the database that it should start decrypting now.
        """
        if self.__db_empty():
            self.connected = True
            return
        if self.encrypt:
            try:
                if not self.new_db:
                    self.__decrypt_db()
                self.connected = True
                self.__load_db_file()
            except InvalidToken:
                quit("Wrong password for database!")

    def done(self) -> None:
        """
        Indicates to the database that it should start encrypting now.
        """
        if not self.connected:
            quit("Please call .connect() to connect to database!")
        if self.encrypt:
            self.__encrypt_db()
            self.connected = False

    def __create_db_file(self) -> None:
        """
        Creates a database file with the name of the database as the filename.
        """
        if not os.path.exists(self.file_name):
            _ = open(self.file_name, "w").close()
            self.new_db = True

    def __load_db_file(self) -> None:
        """
        Load the database into the current database dictionary.
        """
        with open(self.file_name, "r") as db_file:
            try:
                json.load(db_file)
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                print("Previous database not found. Creating new database.")
                self.db = {}

    def __encrypt_db(self) -> None:
        """
        Encrypts the database with Fernet.
        """
        with open(self.file_name, 'rb') as db_file:
            db = db_file.readline()
            encrypted = self.fernet.encrypt(db)
        
        with open(self.file_name, 'wb') as db_file:
            db_file.write(encrypted)

    def __decrypt_db(self) -> None:
        """
        Decrypts the database with Fernet.
        """
        with open(self.file_name, 'rb') as db_file:
            db = db_file.readline()
            decrypted = self.fernet.decrypt(db)
        
        with open(self.file_name, 'wb') as db_file:
            db_file.write(decrypted)

    def __db_empty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Determines if the database if empty.
        """
        with open(self.file_name, "r") as db_file:
            return not db_file.readlines()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"DB: {self.name}"

class PasswordLengthError(Exception):
    """
    Raised when the user enters a password less than 32 characters long.
    """

    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(message)
```

Below is an example file of how an average user would work with this database:

**`test_db.py`**

```
from lindb import LinDB

# Example password 32 characters long #

pw = "zSLfLhAvjhmX6CrzCbxSE2dzXEZaiOfO"

db = LinDB("DB_TEST", pw=pw)

# Decrypts the file if the password is correct #

db.connect()

# Start inserting pairs #

db.insert({"Ben": 16})
db.insert({"Hannah": 17})
db.insert({"Will": 18})

# Query database and display results #

results = [
    db.query(value=16),
    db.query(key="Hannah"),
    db.query(key="Will", value=18),
    db.query(key="Test")
]
for result in results:
    print(result)

# Demonstrating the ability to use assignment expressions #
# Should the key and/or value not exist, None is returned #

if result := db.query(key="Be"):
    print(result)

# This writes the current database to the file #

db.save()

# Encrypts the file #

db.done()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both impressive and ambitious!

### Passwords

> the absolute requirement of a 32 character long password ensures it will take a considerable amount of time to break the encryption

It will also ensure that some users will be writing that password down or saving it to a text file, defeating the entire purpose of a password. A softer approach would be, during the password saving procedure, do an entropy check with a library that provides this. Issue a warning if the entropy is below a predetermined value.

> I let Fernet decide if the password is correct, instead of implementing something myself. Is this a good way of going about this?

Yes!

### Performance

> I'm also fairly concerned about the time between each encrypt and decrypt. Should I only decrypt when the user wants to insert or query the database?

That's a loaded question. If you expect your database to be potentially massive (over the size of RAM), then some of it will need to stay on disc, and it might as well stay encrypted there.

The bigger question is: how do you cache your data? If the cache is aggressively memory-resident, it might be considered a security weakness to hold onto unencrypted contents in RAM for long periods of time. Another factor is the maximum acceptable latency between receiving a query, decrypting the contents on-the-fly if necessary and returning the result. Yet another factor is convenience of use: is authentication per-query, or per-session? I've never seen any databases authenticate per-query, but it's not entirely out of the question.

I don't have good answers to these, so I suggest that you do some testing at scale.

### Private methods

> the double underscore ones, such as __encrypt_db. I'm familiar with the purpose of hiding functions that are meant to be internal. Am I using this convention correctly?

Not really. It should just be `_encrypt_db`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name).

### Top-level classes

You're in Python 3, so these parens are not necessary:

```
class LinDB():
```

### Type hints

```
pair: Dict
```

A dictionary of what? `Dict[str, str]`? Also,

```
name, pw=None
```

is probably

```
name: str, pw: Optional[str] = None
```

### Overambitious methods

This return type:

```
Union[None, List[Any], bool]
```

is a huge red flag that your query method is not specific enough, and trying to do too many things at once. I think your callers will not find the merging of all of these invocations convenient, and would benefit instead from you separating this out into `query_for_key`, `query_for_value`, etc.

Comment: `callers will not find the merging of all of these invocations convenient` Maybe... Commenting as a heavy user key value stores, I **LOVE** when libraries make a single accessible method for query and perform their own control flow based on my input.  Query optimization doesn't need to be a sql exclusive subsystem.  I can pipeline the creation of a query upstream in my app like `q={'key':<something from user>}` or  `q={'value':<something from user>}` far away from the actual database query.  My code calls `lib.query(**q)`  I'd very much prefer not implementing my own query control flow.

Comment: @bauman.space It's precisely because developers shouldn't implement their own control flow that these methods should be separated. It's conceivable that a caller would need to follow `query()` with a long sequence of `if isinstance` to figure out exactly what happened.